# Use template with templateUrl

Tags: angular

I have a component like this :

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './drawings.component.html',
    animations: [appModuleAnimation()],
    styleUrls: ['./styles.css'],
})

export class DrawingsComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
}
```

And another component like this :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'gallery',
    template: `
    <div class="modal fade" id="selectedImageModal" >

    </div>
    `,
    styles: [`

  `]
})
export class GalleryComponent {

    @Input() datasource;
    selectedImage;

    setSelectedImage(image) {
        this.selectedImage = image;
    }
}
```

So now I need to inject the `gallery` component into the `DrawingsComponent` component.How can I do that ? If I have inline template then I can do that as shown below.But I'm using `templateUrl` on  `DrawingsComponent`.

```
 template: `
    <gallery [datasource]=images></gallery>
  `,
```

Comment: `<gallery [datasource]=images></gallery>` put this line in `./drawings.component.html`.what's wrong with it?

Comment: What does "I need to inject the gallery component into the DrawingsComponent" mean? How is template and templateUrl related? You can put the same content into a template and templateUrl. templateUrl only means that the HTML template content is written in an external file instead in the same file as the components class (TS) content.

Comment: are you telling me to put that inside the `drawings.component.html` ? if yes then how can I pass the `images` array to it ? @micronyks

Comment: Templates are linked with their components so they can access the properties declared on the components. If images is declared in your DrawingsComponent it will be available to its template

Comment: WHat do you mean by `how to pass the images`? same way as you are doing with `template syntax`.

Comment: yes,my Bad.Thanks a lot :) @micronyks

Comment: Yes,you're right.It is my fault.Thanks a lot :) @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same thing in your drawings.component.html (in template or templateUrl)

```
<gallery [datasource]="images"></gallery>
```

Templates are linked with their components so they can access the properties/methods declared on the components.

In this case, you are passing the images from your DrawingsComponent as the input of your GalleryComponent which should work okay.

Comment: Yes,My bad.Thanks a lot :)